# webcam builtin mic only works after replugged on xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, webcam, microphone

I have a usb webcam with builtin mic. When I switch on the pc, the mic is not working (in volume control I can not see the mic input meter bar). If I unplug the webcam and replug it, then the mic starts working.

Note that the webcam is working without re-plug.

I found a similar question here: [USB Webcam microphone not working until re-plugged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017925/usb-webcam-microphone-not-working-until-re-plugged)

And I tried to comment the line

load-module module-suspend-on-idle

in /etc/pulse/default.pa but that did not solve my problem.

I checked the output of "pacmd list-sources" before and after the re-plug, and found that a few values seems strangely changing, but maybe that's ok, I am not an expert in this... Anyway this is the diff of the "pacmd list-sources" outputs:

```
43c43
<   * index: 1
---
>   * index: 2
55c55
<       current latency: 393355,61 ms
---
>       current latency: 0,95 ms
63,64c63,64
<       card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02>
<       module: 8
---
>       card: 2 <alsa_card.usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02>
>       module: 27
78c78
<               alsa.long_card_name = "AVEO Technology Corp. USB2.0 Camera at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7, high speed"
---
>               alsa.long_card_name = "AVEO Technology Corp. USB2.0 Camera at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8, high speed"
80,81c80,81
<               device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.7:1.2"
<               sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.2/sound/card1"
---
>               device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.8:1.2"
>               sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:1.2/sound/card1"
92c92
<               device.buffering.fragment_size = "96000"
---
>               device.buffering.fragment_size = "482"
```

"pacmd input-sources" output before unplug (mic not working):

```
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 73454 / 112% / 2,97 dB,   front-right: 73454 / 112% / 2,97 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371,52 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xff87c000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "3b56"
        device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (OptiPlex 980)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_input.usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02.mono-fallback>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9040
    volume: mono: 64909 /  99% / -0,25 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 19201 /  29% / -31,99 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 393355,61 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 2000,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB2.0 Camera"
        alsa.long_card_name = "AVEO Technology Corp. USB2.0 Camera at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.7:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.2/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1871"
        device.vendor.name = "Aveo Technology Corp."
        device.product.id = "0143"
        device.product.name = "USB2.0 Camera"
        device.serial = "AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "hw:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "192000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "96000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.description = "USB2.0 Camera Mono"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

"pacmd input-sources" output after re-plug (mic WORKING):

```
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 73454 / 112% / 2,97 dB,   front-right: 73454 / 112% / 2,97 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371,52 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xff87c000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "3b56"
        device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (OptiPlex 980)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 2
    name: <alsa_input.usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02.mono-fallback>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9040
    volume: mono: 64909 /  99% / -0,25 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 19201 /  29% / -31,99 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,95 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 2000,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02>
    module: 27
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB2.0 Camera"
        alsa.long_card_name = "AVEO Technology Corp. USB2.0 Camera at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.8:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:1.2/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1871"
        device.vendor.name = "Aveo Technology Corp."
        device.product.id = "0143"
        device.product.name = "USB2.0 Camera"
        device.serial = "AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "hw:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "192000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "482"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.description = "USB2.0 Camera Mono"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

What shall I do to be able to use the mic without re plugging the webcam?

Comment: Try and see if `uhubctl` (it's in the Ubuntu repos) works for you. If your h/w is supported, move webcam to a supported port. Then, you can power cycle the port from a script or startup command.